# Legacy Values Left In Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, filterfunction

I'm currently using a Google spreadsheet that has many filter functions and many sheets, when one value is changed on one sheet the filter function on the other sheets is changed due to the condition changing and a recalculation occurs.

The bug seems to be that sometimes data from the previous filter function is left in the cells and is not cleared automatically. I have made a quick script that clears cells that have the potential to hold old data, which works but shouldn't be the case.

Has anyone else ever had this issue?

Thanks and I hope this has been explained well enough.

Comment: This could be more likely due to huge number of filter functions/sheets, as it would take time to update them all.

If you could recreate your issue with a small scale data Or provide a step-by-step reproduction of the issue, you can create an issue at https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker/guides/create-issue-ui#create_an_issue to report this.

Comment: It's very hard to recreate as it's totally random and it seems like the values have just been typed in there. When I go to show edit history the ce is completely empty but is showing a value because it came from the filter function. I also wondered if maybe it is a bug due to the sheet being shared!? Maybe it is loading incorrectly there? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Since the issue randomly occurs, it would be quite tricky to provide the actual issue. However, if you encounter it by any chance, please capture enough details that you can provided to https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker/guides/create-issue-ui#create_an_issue so that it can be properly checked. This is more likely a bug.